# How do I get into this tube?

Tags: unmechanical

In *Unmechanical*, you control the most adorable little robot ever as he bumps his way through puzzles of varying difficulty.

Problem is, I'm stuck at a mere 5 minutes into the game!

[image]

I already picked up the little glowy orb and dropped it into the open tube, which I *assumed* would open the red, closed tube. But it didn't.

**How do I open this red tube?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, as it turns out, putting the glowy orb into the open tube *does* open the red, closed tube.

It can apparently bug out when lowering the glowy orb, which is exactly what happened in this case. If this happens, simply quit to the Main Menu and select Continue. You'll be placed at a checkpoint just before this bit, and the glowy orb will be back where you originally found it.